# Eloquent : find user with maximum pivot data (Alltime and of the month)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Still learning with Laravel, and I'm struggling with Eloquent.

I've got these two tables, users and contents. The foreign key contents.user_id is correctly set, and I wanted to query two things :

- The user which has the maximum of contents (with the count)
- The user which has the maximum content for the last 30 days (Also with the count).

I'd put an Eloquent query, but I can't find anything to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've been able to tell, you cannot constraint the result of the root object from the related object. By this I mean, you can't restrict the Users fetched based on results in content. Considering this, you need to approach these queries from the other side, `Content`.

```
Content::groupBy('user_id')
    ->orderByRaw('count(`posts`.`id`) desc')
    ->first()->user;
```

This should generate the following 2 queries:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `contents` 
GROUP BY `user_id` 
ORDER by count(`posts`.`id`) DESC
LIMIT 1

SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1
```

Limiting based on time is fairly easy as well:

```
$date = (new DateTime('-1 month'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
Content::where('created_at', '>=', $date)
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->orderByRaw('count(`posts`.`id`) desc')
    ->first()->user;
```

Comment: Thanks A LOT ! I'm starting to better understand eloquent. I just updated your datetime to use carbon : `$date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime('-1 month'))->toDateTimeString();`

Comment: You can simplify that to Carbon::parse('-1 month')->toDateTimeString()